# Finding unknown string with known format in a text

Tags: excel, string, vba

How can I find a string with format `xx.xx.xx` (could be numbers or letters) using a formula in MS Excel?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This question is offtopic, because you ask us for you to find a tool to solve your problem. This is not how SO works :/

Comment: Btw, why are you tagging C++? There is nothing C++ related in your question :(

Comment: You originally tagged this question with the C++ language tag (now edited away). Why? Are you programming in C++? Do you want a C++ solution? Or is this a pure Excel question?

Comment: *Welcome to Stack Overflow*  Be sure to check out the [tour] (you'll earn your first badge!) Could you please show a **sample** of your data, and expand on your explanation of what you're trying to do, what you've tried, and what the end result would look like?  Also check out tips in "[ask]" as well as **how to create a [mcve].**

Comment: sorry guys, just chaged the tags

Comment: @HaniaCiućka why the tag [tag:dax]?

Comment: @hellow - there's nothing related to [tag:excel] or [tag:vba] in the question either... just saying'.  ;)

Comment: i thought that i could use 'search' function but the problem is, the string i wanna find is unknown

Comment: Your looking for search using regex or globbing.

Comment: @ashleedawg "...in one column of excel sheet." is kinda excel related, no? ;)

Answer (score 3):

Try,

```
=MID(A1, SEARCH("??.??.??", A1), 8)
```

[image]

Comment: How is it that I've *never* used [the `SEARCH` function](https://support.office.com/article/search-searchb-functions-9ab04538-0e55-4719-a72e-b6f54513b495)?

Comment: amazing thank you, i would need to do some adjustments but that exactly what I've been looking for !

Comment: @Jeeped: good answer, unfortunately, as it's very likely to get positive upvotes, it means the question won't be deleted :)

Perhaps we can edit the question to fit your answer :)

Comment: @OurManinBananas, I just based this response on *has a format xx.xx.xx (could be numbers or letters)'*.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a regex that can be used as an user defined function in the sheet. Currently set up to only retrieve one result per cell but could be extended easily.

Try the [regex here](https://regex101.com/r/LO8Hz0/2).

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub TEST()
    Dim tests(), i As Long
    tests = Array("11.22.33 avx", "abc 11.22.33 cdvdsds", "111.22.33", "1.22.33", "11.22.33.22", "dd.dd.dd.dd", "dd.dd.dd")

    For i = LBound(tests) To UBound(tests)
        Debug.Print GetID(tests(i))
    Next
End Sub

Public Function GetID(ByVal inputString As String) As String
  With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = True
            .Pattern = "(?:^|[^.])\b((?:[A-Za-z0-9]{2}\.){2}[A-Za-z0-9]{2}\b)(?!\.)"
            If .TEST(inputString) Then
              GetID = .Execute(inputString)(0).submatches(0)
            Else
              GetID = vbNullString
            End If
  End With
End Function
```

Thanks to @RonRosenfeld for improving the regex from an initial horror of:

```
.Pattern = "(:?^|\s)([A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9]\.[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9]\.[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9]){1,8}(?=\s|$)"
```

to

```
.Pattern = "(?:^|[^.])\b((?:[A-Za-z0-9]{2}\.){2}[A-Za-z0-9]{2}\b)(?!\.)"
```

---

**All matches:**

For a comma separated list of all matches adapt the function as follows:

```
Public Function GetID(ByVal inputString As String) As String
    Dim matches As Object, total As Long, arr(), i As Long
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .Pattern = "(?:^|[^.])\b((?:[A-Za-z0-9]{2}\.){2}[A-Za-z0-9]{2}\b)(?!\.)"
        If .TEST(inputString) Then
            Set matches = .Execute(inputString): total = matches.Count - 1
            ReDim arr(0 To total)
            For i = 0 To total
                arr(i) = matches(i).Submatches(0)
            Next
            GetID = Join(arr, Chr$(44))
        Else
            GetID = vbNullString
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: You probably want to add the word boundary tokens around it.  Maybe `(?:[A-Za-z0-9]{2}\.){2}[A-Za-z0-9]{2}\b`.  And, of course, with `Global = True`, it will return multiple matches.  Then you don't need the `Trim` or looking for spaces, start/end of string

Comment: Thanks @RonRosenfeld I will go through your suggestions. I am only returning one match at present from the function but left open the possibility of extending to return an array of matches potentially.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld It matches on these cases 11.22.33.22 , 
dd.dd.dd.dd   when it shouldn't. The problem I had with trying to shorten using syntax for repeating group such as {2} was that I could no longer specify the total length at the end with {1,8}. I am a regex beginner so any further pointers welcome.

Comment: With the above pattern, `Set MC = .Execute(inputString)`.  Where MC has been declared as an `Object`, will return a collection of all the Matches in the string.

Comment: Of course, (slapping forehead), that's because of the dot triggering the \b.  Let me think

Comment: I still have a leading space character to eliminate from the regex which I am currently using Trim for so bear that in mind as there is definitely scope for lots of improvement! I don't think I can use a lookbehind to get rid of that though.

Comment: Try:  `(?:^|[^.])\b((?:[A-Za-z0-9]{2}\.){2}[A-Za-z0-9]{2}\b)(?!\.)` and return capturing group #1.  And you are correct about look-behinds -- don't exist in vbscript

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Very nice answer. Do you want to post that yourself?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179017/discussion-between-qharr-and-ron-rosenfeld).

Comment: @QHarr: it's a shame the question wasn't written better originally, as it has two excellent answers!

Comment: @OurManinBananas That is true :-( It was a nice experience for me though have another SO user help me out. Nicer when that happens than the fly by down votes.